# Showing that if $AB=BA$ then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A \in M_n$ has distinct eigenvalues $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and that $A$ commutes with a given matrix $B \in M_n$  so that $AB=BA$.
>
> a. Prove A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable

I was able to show that $B$ is diagonalizable but I cannot figure out how to show that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Hint: $\;D=P^{-1}ABP=P^{-1}APP^{-1}BP\;$ ...and now use $\;AB=BA\;$

Comment: I am not sure I get the hint I think I have to find non singular matrix that diagonalizes A and B but how how............... how

Comment: But how do you know $D=P^-1 AB P$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having distinct eigenvalues means that for each eigenvalue $\lambda$, there is a one dimensional subspace $S(\lambda)$ spanned by the respective eigenvector $x$. In this case $Ax=\lambda x$, ans $A(Bx)=B(Ax)=\lambda (Bx)$ so $Bx\in S(\lambda)$ and hence $Bx=\beta x$ for some $\beta$. Therefore $x$ is also an eigenvector of $B$. So $A$ and $B$ have same eigenvectors and therefore can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Comment: So if you have the same eigen vector then they can be simultaneously diagonalzied?

Comment: Yes in this case, try to change the basis of your space to $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$,  eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$. $A$ and $B$ in the new basis become diagonal. Writing down the change-of-basis transformation give you the diagonalization.

Answer (score 2):

Under these conditions, each eigenspace of $A$ is one-dimensional. Further, $B$ fixes each of these eigenspaces: namely, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $$A(Bx)=BAx=B\lambda x=\lambda (Bx).$$ It follows that $B$ maps each eigenvector of $A$ to its multiple and hence $B$ is diagonal in a basis consisting of $A$-eigenvectors.